# How to make java Object visible in Sub mxml to Main mxml file in Flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

In my Application using Flex-Blazeds-java...,in my Flex application side have two mxml file

1. Main.mxml
2. Login.mxml

In Main.mxml file have button called `Login` click this button one popup open that is called `Login.mxml`
in this File i have authentication logic to connect java...sample code`

```
public var userService:UserService = new UserService();
[Bindable] public var userVO1:UserVO = new UserVO();
protected function loginUser(event:MouseEvent):void
{

var rpcAuthenticateUser:AsyncToken = userService.authenticateUser(userid_id.text, password_id.text);//Hear authenticateUser(-,-) is a java method it return UserVO object
rpcAuthenticateUser.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(handler_success, handler_failure));

}
private function handler_failure(event:FaultEvent): void {
Alert.show("in handler_failure :" + event.message);

}


   private function handler_success(event:ResultEvent): void {
    userVO = event.result as UserVO;
     Alert.show("test "+userVO.loginId);
        }
```

Hear Login Working Perfectly according my Database logic and also if it is ResultEvent the Alert box show correct value (for ex:loginId is '`narasimham`')...and everthing working perfectly no default in Login.mxml

```
Now The Problem Start...
```

I want to Use `UserVO` object in Main.mxml file so in that i'm using following code..

```
     public var loginUserVar:Login = new Login();
  protected function afterLoginUser(event:FlexEvent):void
   {
    Alert.show("LoginId ="+loginUserVar.userVO.loginId);        
   }
```

Actually my thinking this Alert box giving value `narasimham` but it is giving `null` value.

Why it is giving Null value?Is their any Scope specify to create variable?

Comment: Where are you copying the value into loginUserVar?

Comment: just i'm creating object to Login mxml file only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Ethrbunny i'm not store the value of userVO object so it is not available to Out side mxml file....

That's way in Flex(3.5) Application in Login.mxml file i'm adding following code...

```
Application.application.userVO = event.result as UserVO;
//Hear userVO is Object defined in Main.mxml file....
```

Answer (score 1):

In `handler_success` you need to set the value of `userVO1` otherwise it won't be available otuside of your mxml file. You also need to to reference it in `afterLoginUser` as `userVO1` instead of `userVO`.